# Extracting data from GeoMedia *.mdf database without using GeoMedia?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, database, geomedia

Is it possible to extract data from Geomedia .mdf without Geomedia?

Preferably with use of QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: I may be wrong here but rather it stands for Main Data File or something alike. Its definetly database file dedicated for SQL server. It usually comes with .ldf which is generated after connection to SQL server. You can work on those in Arc or other software which use SQL servers. Perhaps my question should be, if I can make use of GeoMedia database in other GIS, considering differences in file/object structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its not entirely an anwser. However my problem is solved. As I managed to export .shp from GeoMedia at the office. I had to install SQL SERVER EXPRESS, hook up .mdf to the server and connect from GeoMedia to SQL SERVER in order to read database. Still in question, if it is feasible to make use of .mdf database made in GeoMedia in other GIS soft, which supports SQL?

Comment: Once you hook up a .mdf to sql server (express) it becomes a regular SQL Server database. With sql server management studio (express) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796 you can investigate what is inside the database, tables, functions and so on. I don't have a geomedia mdf, but I don't think this would be to hard. You will probably come across some strange blobs in the database. See if you can find any functions in the database that operate on the blob and you will probably get more insight on what Intergraph is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Only Geomedia .mdb

and
Geomedia SQL Server Warehouse can be converted

Using Safe Software's [FME Desktop](http://www.safe.com/products/fme-desktop/)

[image]

Comment: This sound quite interesting. I'll have a look, as it may be usefull also for some my other problems. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

The statemnet GeoMedia .mdf is not really correct. The only propriatary format geomedia writes to is an Access Database, like the Personal Geodatabase from ArcGIS. The.mdf is an SQL Server / Express data file. GeoMedia makes use of the Spatial capabilities of SQL Server / Express to store data. The .ldf records the log files so you do not really need this unless you want to roll back transactions.

Long story short, install SQL Express (Free) attach the .mdf file and other applications can access the same data. Depending on the version of GeoMedia you have, you really do not need FME because GeoMedia can import and Export to sevral GIS data formats.