# How to connect to Geomedia data in Acess .mdb from ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access, geomedia

I can't connect to an Access database from a GIS platform.

I tried ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS but I did not succeed.

I specify that this Access database was used in GeoMedia and export it to access (.mdb)

Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and expand your question - give specific details about what you have tried, and what the error messages are.

Comment: No the mdb.database have geometry feature exemple : roads, rivers, admin.border and others and the geometric feature which i couldn't open connect or open in arc gis

Comment: I have not errors because i can't connect to arc gis !!!

Comment: I have just a .mdb file and i need to get the geometric feature from this .mdb

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide any requested clarifications. Are you saying that you created this Access file in GeoMedia?  And that you are trying to read it and display geometries from it in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: I recive from someone a database in mdb format that was exported from geomedia, and i can not open it in arc gis or in qgis

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to comments requesting *edits* for clarification. You reduce the chances of this question being answered by failing to improve the question. Take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how GIS SE works.

Comment: Hope this will help https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/tables/connecting-to-a-microsoft-access-database.htm

Comment: Part of the problem is that your directionality is wrong:  Databases don't connect to application software, application software connects to databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to link ArcGIS to MS Access and use that DB?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36881/is-there-a-way-to-link-arcgis-to-ms-access-and-use-that-db)

Comment: The down and close votes are a bit excessive for this question. Yes the Q is poorly formulated in English, but it is also clear English is not the OP's mother tongue; some forbearance and patience is in order. There is enough info in the Q to get to an answer (specifically: this is a Geomedia mdb).

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a way to link ArcGIS to MS Access and use that DB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36881/is-there-a-way-to-link-arcgis-to-ms-access-and-use-that-db) addresses how to connect to an Access Database.

One thing that is important to note, is that there needs to be a spatial component in your database in order for it to open in ArcGIS, but it will also need to be in a format readable by ArcMap.  If you've ever opened the back end of a geodatabase, you will see multiple tables that are strictly for reading/formatting/conversion that ArcMap uses in the background and the user doesn't see.

In a quick Google Search, I found [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1149&t=300419), which references using FME software, which makes me believe that the two database formats will not automatically jive with one another and will need some conversion in order to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Like ArcGIS, GeoMedia uses the Access .mdb file for one of it's own proprietary data storage formats. The only thing in common between Esri's [personal-gdb](/questions/tagged/personal-gdb) and Geomedia's .mdb is the extension.

GDAL/OGR 1.9+ has a read-only driver for the [Geomedia MDB database](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geomedia.html). You should be able to use [ogr2ogr](/questions/tagged/ogr2ogr) utility to convert the contents into data usable by both ArcGIS and Qgis. The command line might look like:

`ogr2ogr D:\path\to\out_folder in_geomedia.mdb`

Also see [Extracting data from GeoMedia *.mdf database without using GeoMedia?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7922/extracting-data-from-geomedia-mdf-database-without-using-geomedia) and [QGIS & GeoMedia .mdb .gws compatibility?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46909/qgis-geomedia-mdb-gws-compatibility)